# while($array = mysql_fetch_array($queryresults) && $i <= '9' ){ echo "stuff" }

Tags: php

So I have a query, and though my query can possibly return 20 results, I only want it to show the first 9 results. There is a dumb reason I'm not just limiting the query results to 9, for this purpose I need to know how to stop the while function if $i reaches 9.

Code is

```
    $i = 0;
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($queryresults) && $i <= '9')
    {
               echo $array['id'];
               $i++;
    }
```

How do I get it to stop putting out more echoes after 9th result? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the limiting condition first will also make sure you only fetch 9 rows, not and 10 and one discard because `&&` is called *lazy* (if the first part is false, it wont even look at the next part).

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 9 && $array = mysql_fetch_array($queryresults)){
    echo $array['id'];
    $i += 1;
}
```

or if you want to be fancy:

```
$i = 9;
while($i-- > 0 && $array = mysql_fetch_array($queryresults)){
    echo $array['id'];
}
```

But I find this error prone ..

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I find it to be this way too but it's a strange circumstance that I have to do this :\ My boss just needs it to be done this way supposedly.. so.. doing it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0;
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($queryresults) && $i++ < 9)
    echo $array['id'];
}
```

Notes:

1. No need to put `9` in quotes
2. You can increment-after-compare by doing `$i++` in the `while` loop condition (although you don't have to, you could also put it after `echo $array['id']` in the while loop body).
3. Careful!  You want `< 9` and not `<= 9` since starting at zero, or you'll get 10 iterations of the loop.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your `$i++`  needs to be inside the while loop

You should also have `$i <= 9` instead of `$i <= '9'` but it should still work as is

Answer (score 0):

'9' needs to be 9

```
$i = 0;
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($queryresults) && $i < 9){
    echo $array['id'];
    $i += 1;
}
```